# Integral of the form $\int_a^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, inverse-function

I desire to evaluate $$I=\int_1^{e+1}f^{-1}(t)\,dt$$ where $f(x)=x+\log x\, $

My try was to let $t=f(u)\,$ in order to get $$I=\int uf'(u)\,du=uf(u)-\int f(u)\,du$$  and the integral was pretty much over, however I dont know how to get the new bounds after substituting and finding the inverse I think is pretty hard. I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lower bound, you have that $t=1$. Since $t=f(u)$, you can set those equal, and you get $f(u)=1$. Since $f(x) =x+\log(x)$, you have $u+\log(u)=1$, and by inspection, $u=1$. For the upper bound, it's more complicated if you actually have $\log(x)$, but if you instead have $\ln(x)$, then the upper bound is $e$. (Note that $\log$, with no qualification, is generally understood to mean log base 10; if you want log base $e$, it's best to write as $\ln$ to avoid confusion).

Both the manipulation of the bounds, and solving for $u$, is simplified by the fact that $f$ is monotonic. If you had a non-monotonic function, much of what you did, and much of my answer, would not be valid.

Another way of looking at this is that integral can be interpreted as the area under a curve. Taking the inverse switches $x$ and $y$. So instead of finding the area by going from left to right and taking the height, you can go from bottom to top and take the width.

Comment: In fact in this context, $\log$ with no subscript almost always means $\log_e,$ which is the same as $\ln.$ It is true that secondary-school textbooks and remedial secondary-school "precalculus" textbooks still say $\log$ with no subscript means base-$10$ logarithm, and that is unfortunate.

Comment: Have you considered altering your unqualified statement that $\log$ without qualification, means base-10 logarithm? In some contexts, in the usage of some people, it may mean that; in this context it is standard that it means base-e. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy In your statement "in this context it is standard that it means base-e", the phrase "in this context" is a qualification. Thus, I don't find it to contradict my statement that "log", without qualification, means base 10. Both Google's calculator and Excel give log(10) as being 1. I've never seen the default base of log be anything but 10. But I've modified my statement a bit.

Comment: But log without qualification should not be taken to mean base 10. Certainly calculators do that, but the reason for taking 10 to be the default was made obsolete by calculators.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $f$ is monotonic

$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) \, dx + \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = bf(b) - af(a),$$

and $f(1) = 1, f(e) = e + 1$

Answer (score 0):

The formula is
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}\left(x\right)dx=\left[xf\left(x\right)\right]_a^b-\int_a^bf\left(x\right)dx$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry now its correct